# Xcode: table view cells only being created when I use a breakpoint. Why?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, touch, breakpoints

When I put a break point right on the line 
"if (coordinator!= nil){" 
the table view that is created from core data works correctly.

If I remove or put the breakpoint anywhere before that in my code it does not show the table view cells.

```
- (NSManagedObjectContext *) sharedManagedObjectContext {
if (_managedObjectContext != nil) {
    return _managedObjectContext;
}

NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
if (coordinator != nil) {
    _managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
    [_managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator: coordinator];
    [_managedObjectContext setMergePolicy:NSMergeByPropertyStoreTrumpMergePolicy];
```

}

```
return _managedObjectContext;
```

}

I have no clue as to how this is happening and had very little luck finding any other situations similar to this one.

Thank you for your help in advance!

Edit 1:

Here is the code that is being used to fetch the data from coredata

```
- (BOOL) setupFetchedResultsController:(NSError **) error {

self.managedObjectContext = [[PhotoBreezePersistentStoreManager shared] sharedManagedObjectContext];

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

[fetchRequest setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"GeoTrack" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext]];

NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"trackName" ascending:NO]; 

NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

NSFetchedResultsController *controller = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc]
                                          initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                          managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext
                                          sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                          cacheName:nil];

controller.delegate = self;

self.fetchedResultsController = controller;

return [controller performFetch:error];
```

}

If I put a breakpoint in any of the above code...

after: "self.managedObjectContext = [[PhotoBreezePersistentStoreManager shared] sharedManagedObjectContext];"

... it will still work.

I'm pretty new to objective-c/cocoa so im not absolutely sure if a queue or thread is involved. I will however look into what you mentioned 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not enough information to really say;   you would need to post details related to the creation/population of the table view.

However, this does sound like a classic race condition.  Any threads or queues involved?

Comment: I posted the code that fetches the data from coredata. Hopefully it will help. Probably be soe weird timing problem that I'll have to keep trying to debug. Thanks!

Comment: What is calling `setupFetchedResultsController:`?